# How to use cURL to verify a web page is fully loaded?

Tags: linux, bash, curl

I have a case where after deploying to a server, the UI of my web page takes around 20 mins to load. The API is available almost immediately. 
I need a way to use curl to load a  web page and verify from the response that whether the web page is loaded or not.

Comment: @Arount  . i do not have much experience with bash scripts, I could use curl with request to get the status of what the API returns, but could not find anywhere if I can check wheter the client side code is rendered through the command line

Answer (score 2):

Combining curl with grep you can request your page and see if it loads by looking for a specific string you'd expect to see when it renders correctly.

Something like:

```
curl -o - https://www.example.com/ | grep "Something from successful response"
if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo "Success"
else
    echo "Fail" 
fi
```

The `-o -` option to curl outputs the response to `stdout` which is then piped to grep which looks for a specific string from a successful.  Depending on your needs there may be other ways but this sounds like it matches what you're asking.

Also note if your UI takes 20 minutes to load the first time, you might need to adjust some curl options (e.g. `--max-time`) to allow for longer timeouts.